# Install ActionBar-PullToRefresh on eclipse without gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to install the [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) whithout the gradle. I download the source and I go on Import->Existing Android Code Into Workspace but for a reason I don't know it doesn't let me to import it (see image below). I see other posts and the solution was to import it like this way but for me doesn't work. I'm new and I'm sorry for this dump question. Thanks :)

[image: Import fail image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you already have projects named **main** and **MainActivity** in your workspace.

Click on every projects path and then click on it's name and change it.

Comment: I did but after that I can't import the library on my project.
[see image](http://s1.postimg.org/bpl8ib8cv/aasdddd.jpg)

Comment: Right click on the library in workspace and select Properties. And in the Android section is the "Is Library" checked?